# Armature with vertex painting cause hand to deform when rotating

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature, weight-painting, parent

So all the bones work except the hand. Attached are a few pics of what I mean:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLlhM.jpg

Only part of the hand rotates, and I've tried weight painting the entire hand, but it still does the same deform. I've tried adding in an IK for the hand which also doesn't seem to help. If it helps, the fingers (Which work just fine) are all parented to the hand bone.

I've tried searching, but it seems that people are stuck on the mesh deforming once the armature is applied, as opposed to when rotating or manipulating the armature.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: I guess another bone influences your hand mesh, so you could select the vertices and in the Properties panel > Data > Vertex Groups, click the down arrow on the right of the vertex group list and click Remove From All Groups, then reassign to the hand group

Comment: Thank you for responding. I tried removing all vertices manually, clear parenting and yet the issue persists. Fixed issue

Had to re-parent and then re-parent the fingers to hand, it kept going to the arm, Thank you for helping.